# Javascript Closure Within a For Loop (2 closures involved - an $http.get call and a $scope.$watch) using angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, anonymous-function, iife

I'm creating an angular app using [angular-google-maps](https://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api). What I'm trying to do is loop through an array of locations in order to place a marker at each location's latitude and longitude. However, because I'm using a couple of closures within my for-loop, a marker is only showing up at the last entry of the array. Here's the code:

```
$scope.petMarkers = [];
$http.get('/api/pets').success(function(foundPets){
  $scope.foundPets = foundPets;
  var listOfPets = $scope.foundPets;
  var markerCreator = function(arrayOfPets){
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfPets.length; i++){
      var singlePet = arrayOfPets[i];
      var petName = arrayOfPets[i].name;
      var identity = singlePet._id;
      var location = singlePet.addressFound;
      var split = location.split(' ');
      var joined = split.join('+');
      var httpAddress = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + joined + '&sensor=false';

      // anonymous function keeps reference to i, and when console.log is called, for loop has already finished and value of i is set to 4
      $http.get(httpAddress).success(function(mapDataAgain){
        var ladder = mapDataAgain.results[0].geometry.location.lat; 
        var longer = mapDataAgain.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
        var obj = {
          latitude: ladder,
          longitude: longer,
          title: petName,
          id: i
        };
        $scope.$watch(function(){
          console.log('we are in scope.watch');
          return $scope.map.bounds;
        }, function(){
          var markers = [];
          //markers.push(obj);
          $scope.petMarkers.push(obj);
          //$scope.petMarkers = markers;
          console.log('markers = ', $scope.petMarkers);
        }, true);
      });
    };
  };
  markerCreator(listOfPets);
});
```

---

Any ideas as to how to use an immediately invoked function expression(IIFE) with this code? I'm having trouble figuring out whether I need two IIFEs (one for the anonymous function called upon success of the $http call and one for the anonymous function called as the argument to $scope.$watch). I'm kind of lost here, so any explanation/help/suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a for loop, and you certainly don't need an IIFE. You have an array of results, so just call the native `.forEach` function. It takes a callback that can is executed on all elements in the array. Benefits of this approach:

- Gives you closure by default. The callback has its own scope and in a way is self-contained and separate from other code. Each element will get its own marker
- Makes your code much easier to read. This is a much too often overlooked detail in coding. You want to strive to avoid any sort of technical debt—one of the easiest ways to do this is use the native array methods. They clearly communicate your code's intentions & makes debugging a lot easier (esp. necessary when asking for help, say on stack overflow, as it takes a lot of time and not many people want to help you if they can't make sense of your code)